# Only check the checkbox if the value of ngModel is true

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox

When my checkbox is clicked the value of my `ngModel` `produto.checked` is set to `true`, but in a moment this value is changed to false without a click in the checkbox. How can i make my checkbox only check/uncheck according by my `ngModel`?

I try something like:

```
<tr *ngFor="let produto of sortedDataProduto; let i = index">
   <input [checked]="produto.checked" [(ngModel)]="produto.checked" name="checkedproduto{{i}}" type="checkbox">
</tr>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in a moment this value is changed to false without a click in the checkbox"?

Answer (score 0):

Delete from your code `[checked]="produto.checked`". `[(ngModel)]="produto.checked"` is enough to show initial value.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding your `produto.checked` twice use either `[checked]` or `[(ngModel)]`
if you still have problem please be more specific.